# How to use asyncio.as_completed() with a variable size task list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

## Challenge

Suppose I have a list L=30 tasks. Each task takes a variable time to complete and has a 10% chance of failing. If a task T fails, add the task back to a queue and prioritize it's completion. Also I can only process at most N=8 number of tasks.

I want to use Python's `asyncio.as_completed()` function to yield the result of a task as soon as it's completed. Once done, add one more task from the task_list L (to make sure we are constantly processing 8 tasks at any given instance).

How can I do this in Python?

## Current Scenario

In my current scenario, I have a queue of L=1000 tasks and at a time I can solve N=20 tasks like this:

```py
# This approach creates a task of all 1000 items in the queue L and then processes them.
while not download_complete():
    task_list = [asyncio.create_task(work()) for work in L]
    for task in asyncio.as_completed(task_list):
        result = await task
        yield result
```

## Problem

The problem however with my current approach is when a task fails, I add it back to the task queue L. Now asyncio.as_completed() will first finish processing all the tasks which are currently already in the task_list before creating a task for all items which have failed during the previous iteration. It's because of this, the failed tasks don't get a priority over the tasks which are already in the task_list.

## Question

So how can I make it so that I can constantly keep processing N number of tasks at a time and yeild the result of the next earliest completion. Once a task is done, fetch one more task from a queue of 1000 tasks and if a task fails, add it back to asyncio.as_completed and prioritize it completion?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to only maintain 8 tasks at a time. Don't create all 1000 tasks at once (after which, you have no easy way to control "priority").

For example:

```py
# Can't really use a `list` here since
# we need to keep track of the original
# coroutine in case of failure, to retry
task_pool = {}

while L:
  # start new tasks until we have 8 running
  while L and len(task_pool) < 8:
    work = L.pop() # last in list = highest priority
    task = asyncio.create_task(work())
    task_pool[task] = work
  
  # grab the first task which completed
  task = next(asyncio.as_completed(task_pool))
  work = tasks.pop(task)

  # yield or retry upon failure
  try:
    yield await completed
  except:
    print("failed!!! retrying")
    L.append(work) # last in list = highest priority
```